# Create a floating GUI button on iOS home screen

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, user-interface, menu

I'm creating an `iOS` swift app that will allow users to play sounds while in another app.  The app is hard to explain, but I would like to know how to create some thing like the assistive touch or the zoom controllers.  Like this: http://www.phonecruncher.com/siteimage/scale/0/0/368401.gif

It's hard to explain, but as you can see there is a button on the screen (it's always on top) and the user needs to be able to open a menu from the button.  The user will play the sounds from here.

Is there any way I can do this in swift in `Xcode`?

Comment: The AssistiveTouch and Zoom menu you mention are part of the OS and Apple don't allow developers to create their own floating menus that can be accessed from the home screen or other apps. Something like this may be possible with a Jailbroken iOS device.